# Marshilling an SAML response object

Tags: xml, marshalling, opensaml

Hi im trying to marshal an SAMLResponse object & im getting the following error. any ideas ?

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xml.security.transforms.params.InclusiveNamespaces.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.opensaml.common.impl.SAMLObjectContentReference.processExclusiveTransform(SAMLObjectContentReference.java:179)
    at org.opensaml.common.impl.SAMLObjectContentReference.createReference(SAMLObjectContentReference.java:145)
    at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller.createSignatureElement(SignatureMarshaller.java:115)
    at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller.marshall(SignatureMarshaller.java:70)
    at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshallChildElements(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:316)
    at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshallInto(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:223)
    at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:174)
    at org.opensaml.common.impl.AbstractSAMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractSAMLObjectMarshaller.java:67)
    at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshallChildElements(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:316)
    at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshallInto(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:223)
    at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:129)
    at org.opensaml.common.impl.AbstractSAMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractSAMLObjectMarshaller.java:59)
    at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:85)
```

Comment: You should post your code

Comment: `Configuration.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller(resp).marshall(resp);` where the resp is my response object

Comment: Fixed .. Thanks .. it was a jar mismatch error

Answer (score 2):

We had the similar error. The problem was with the xml-security:xmlsec:1.0.5D2 dependency which was provided in example from
https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2015/08/sign-assertion-using-opensaml.html

We just commented this dependency out.